# What does one needs to know beforehand when developing an Android app..?

Tags: java, android

I want to build an app in android. I have a sound knowledge of C/C++, but I don't know Java as of yet..!

Do I need to learn java to develop an app in android ?? What does I need to do to develop an app ?

I explored this link http://developer.android.com/training/index.html, but I didn't understand what actually do I need to do to develop an app.

Please help..!

Comment: well android is java so...yeah you need to learn java

Comment: just start to code...

Comment: Download the tools, go through the training step-by-step. It's java, so that would help. Voting to close as "too broad", though.

Comment: Start with an easy tutorial like http://just-another-blog.net/software/create-first-android-mobile-app-tutorial/ , but this blog is my favorite http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html... Enjoy

Comment: This is way too broad a question. Just do the tutorials and do what it is you're planning to do learning what you need when you need it. Java is object oriented, its syntax is very close to C++, so that won't be an issue at all. I started developing in Android only knowing Python at the time and was fine so with C++ you should be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting Android development, you should know these:
1. Basic `OOP` Concepts.
2. Basic `Java`.
3. Basic `XML`.

If you already know these things, then just download `JDK (According to your OS)` and a suitable `IDE` (like `Eclipse`, `Android Studio`, etc)
And explore the [Android Development Portal](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

P.S: If you are finding `Android Developer's Portal` difficult to understand then, you can jump to some nice tutorials and start developing. Here is the list of some nice Android Tuts:
[Vogella's Blog](http://www.vogella.com/android.html)
[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/)
[Core Servelets](http://www.coreservlets.com/android-tutorial/)
[XDA Forum](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/free-android-development-tutorials-on-linux-com/)

Answer (score 0):

YES... You'll need to have basic knowledge of XML and Java. And once you are clear with Object Oriented programming with Java, you can start Android Application Development.